# How to download data in background more than 180 sec? Any hacks?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, download

I have a requirement in iOS. I have download data in the background. But it is limited upto only 180 seconds. Is there anyway that I can renew that 180 seconds? i.e extending the background time..

```
-(void)myDownload{    
   app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];

bgTask = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{

[app endBackgroundTask:bgTask];

bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
        }];

dispatch_async(serial, ^{

[self startMyDownload];

});

}
```

Comment: hey Activate Background mode switch in Target --> capabilities and tick on background fetch

Comment: That one also isn't working :(

Comment: Show your code please don't go for a hack , try as much as usual way

Comment: I have edited my question with code

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set a property in info.plist file for background mode.

Refer attached screen shots[image]

[image]